# Remove metadata from file

Tags: windows-10, permissions, windows-explorer, file-permissions, metadata

I am trying to remove the metadata from a file on Windows 10.

It prompts me for administrator access, which I grant, but it then says `File Access Denied. You require permission from [PC NAME]/[USER] to make changes to this file:` It just keeps asking me to provide permission over and over again.

[image]

The warning they show me when I cancel it.

[image]

Does anybody know what the hell is going on here?

Comment: what kind of file, where is it located?

Comment: @Moab font file. its on the desktop of my main OS drive.

Comment: Move it to a folder you make on the root of C: try again.

Comment: @Moab same issue.

Comment: Can you take Ownership of the file and also ensure you have Full Control permissions, and try again?

Comment: well probably if i fiddle around with `regedit`, but shouldnt there be another way?